# JWT in Request body instead of header

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

Is it possible to receive the .NET Core API JWT in HTTP request's body instead of the header? I tried implementing one myself, but HTTP POST requests don't work.

```
if (ctx.Request.Method.Equals("POST"))
{
    if (ctx.Request.Path.HasValue)
    {
        if (!ctx.Request.Path.Value.Contains("authenticate"))
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                ctx.Request.Body.CopyTo(ms);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(ms))
                {
                    var jsonBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    var body = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BaseRequest>(jsonBody);
                    ctx.Token = body.Token;
                    ctx.Request.Headers["Authorization"] = $"Bearer {body.Token}";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As a result, I get a 400 Bad Request:

```
        "errors": {
            "": [
                "A non-empty request body is required."
            ]
        },
        "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
        "status": 400,
        "traceId": "800000bf-0002-ff00-b63f-84710c7967bb"
```

Comment: This is not a standard approach to send jwt tokens in body i would say.
Please try using common approach: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/08/14/aspnet-core-21-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api

Comment: you can send a JWT however you want. have you tried rewinding the body position prior to copying it?

Comment: @NicklausBrain Thanks for the suggestion, but that's not really possible. The client wants to send them in the body of the POST request only. I managed to find a solution, though.

Answer (score 2):

To the folks that asked me to use a more common approach: Unfortunately, I am unable to do so, due to the client requests I receive.

For anyone needing similar help, this ended up working for me:

```cs
if (ctx.Request.Method.Equals("POST"))
{
    if (ctx.Request.Path.HasValue)
    {
        ctx.Request.EnableRewind();
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ctx.Request.Body.CopyTo(ms);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            ctx.Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(ms))
            {
                var jsonBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
                var body = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BaseRequest>(jsonBody);
                ctx.Token = body.Token;
                ctx.Request.Headers["Authorization"] = $"Bearer {body.Token}";
            }
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```